# Get the year with the greatest count of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Note, I just started learning PostgreSQL for university and English is not my mother tongue.

I need to find the year at which released books are the most popular (year of released books when the most copies were taken).

Here I get three years at which books were released and the number of copies taken:

```
Select distinct book.year, count(copy.nr)
From stud.book, stud.copy
Where copy.taken is not null and book.isbn=copy.isbn
Group by book.year;
```

This is what I get:

```
 year | count
------+-------
 2007 |     2
 2006 |     9
 2005 |     5
 (3 rows)
```

And this is what I really need:

```
 year | count
------+-------
 2006 |     9
```

Because books released in 2006 are the most popular (9 copies were taken of books released in 2006).

Comment: You need to define how to break ties: which year should be chosen if you happen to get a maximum count for more than one?

Answer (score 2):

Use `order by` and `limit 1`:

```
Select book.year, count(copy.nr) as cnt
From stud.book, stud.copy
Where copy.taken is not null and book.isbn=copy.isbn
Group by book.year
Order by cnt desc
Limit 1;
```

Note:  Don't use `distinct` with `group by`, unless you really know what you are doing.  Also, table aliases and explicit `join` syntax make such a query easier to write and to read:

```
Select b.year, count(c.nr) as cnt
From stud.book b join
     stud.copy c
     on b.isbn = c.isbn
Where c.taken is not null
Group by b.year
Order by cnt desc
Limit 1;
```

A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause; *always* use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: For this particular exercise I can't use non-standart functions like LIMIT... But thank you, this example helps to understand it better.

Comment: Then use the ANSI standard `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.  Postgres also supports that.  (I think people tend to prefer `LIMIT` because it is easier to type.)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use appropriate join syntax instead of declaring the `join` conditions in the `where` clause.

One approach to do this is using a `cte`.

```
with counts as (
select book.year, count(copy.nr) as cnt
from stud.book join stud.copy
on book.isbn=copy.isbn
where copy.taken is not null
group by book.year ) 
select * from counts
where cnt = (select max(cnt) as maxcnt from counts)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm :)